# Loading AutoParallaxBackground Andengine Texture

Tags: android, andengine

I'm a rookie in **andengine** . currently I am working a simple andengine game project , where I want to load a **parallax background** . I follow the step as **Nicolas Gramlich** shows in his parallax background example . But I got this problem after running the code a saw a black screen with some blinking colors

I think this is the problem with my **buildableTextureAtlas** and **ParallaxTexture** So here is my code from **ResourceManager** class

```
public ITiledTextureRegion playerTiledTextureRegion;
public ITiledTextureRegion enemyTiledTextureRegion;
public ITextureRegion platformTextureRegion;
public ITextureRegion cloudOneTextureRegion;
public ITextureRegion cloudTwoTextureRegion;
public ITextureRegion cloudThreeTextureRegion;



private BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas gameTextureAtlas;


public BitmapTextureAtlas mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture;

public ITextureRegion mParallaxLayerBack;
public ITextureRegion mParallaxLayerMid;
public ITextureRegion mParallaxLayerFront;

//sounds
Sound soundFall;
Sound soundJump;

//music
Music music;

//font
Font scoreFont;
```

Here is my **LoadResource**() method

```
public void loadResources(){
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    gameTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(mGameActivity.getTextureManager(), 1024,
            512,BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888,TextureOptions.NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    playerTiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas,mGameActivity.getAssets(), 
            "player.png", 3, 1);
    enemyTiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, mGameActivity.getAssets(),
            "enemy.png", 1, 2);
    cloudOneTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, mGameActivity.getAssets(), "cloud1.png");
    cloudTwoTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, mGameActivity.getAssets(), "cloud2.png");

    platformTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, mGameActivity.getAssets(), "platform.png");

    mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mGameActivity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 512);
    mParallaxLayerFront = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, mGameActivity, "parallax_background_layer_front.png", 0, 0);
    mParallaxLayerBack = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, mGameActivity, "parallax_background_layer_back.png", 0, 188);
    mParallaxLayerMid = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, mGameActivity, "parallax_background_layer_mid.png", 0, 669);


    try{
        gameTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(2, 0, 2));

        /*gameTextureAtlas.load();*/
        mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture.load();

    }catch(final TextureAtlasBuilderException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("error while loading textures", e);
    }
}
```

Now from the **GameScene** Class

```
Scene scene = new Scene();
    AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, 200, resManager.mParallaxLayerBack, resManager.vbom)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-5.0f, new Sprite(0, 80, resManager.mParallaxLayerMid, resManager.vbom)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-10.0f, new Sprite(0, 400, resManager.mParallaxLayerFront, resManager.vbom)));
    /*Sprite cloud1 = new Sprite(200,300, resManager.cloudOneTextureRegion, resManager.vbom);
    Sprite cloud2 = new Sprite(300,600, resManager.cloudTwoTextureRegion, resManager.vbom);*/

    scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);
```

Tried to create autoParallaxBackground and set it to the current Scene Object but I got a black and hazy  blinking screen after running the code. Please help me out here. I spend whole night after solving this problem.